# Javascript Variable value in PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I have my code look like this

```
var bal=$(this).val();
var findbalance="<?=balancefromid(bal);?>";
alert(findbalance);
```

is that possible?

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: Hello Pramod, I want to find balance of particular ID received from SELECT. My function balancefromid() is work properly.

Comment: More context detail would be really appreciated. Is that wrapped on a function? When would it execute?

Comment: How best pratice to communicate PHP and Javascript you can use JSON - In PHP side you can use `json_encode($obj_var)` or `json_decode($obj_var)`.

Comment: why is his post being downvoted. i dont get it. i think it is a good question really.

Comment: Do your homework http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: somehow i think his question makes a lot of sense just the way it is formed. i get a feeling u cannot ask that question any better and any more courteously.. His title clearly says Javascript Variable value in PHP and follows it up with code.

Answer (score 2):

No, this won't work because while you can assign JS variables with values from PHP, you cannot do it the other way around without passing the JS values via GET/POST params or via an Ajax call, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should understand how client-side and server-side scripting work, and then you'll understand why this is not possible and unlogical

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're getting confused with developing on the web.
Javascript is a "client-side" language, meaning that it runs on the clients browser AFTER has page has been compiled and sent from the server. This means that there is no PHP/ASP in the code, only HTML & Javascript.

PHP, ASP, JSP are server-side languages which only run on the server-side.

So to answer your question, no you can't directly get the Javascript to call a PHP (server-side) function, but you can post to a PHP page which will then in turn carry out whatever function u like.